# JFrog CLI - Unable to create nested folder while uploading package

Tags: artifactory, github-actions, jfrog-cli

I am here uploading a nuget package to a [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) using [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions) by setup JFrog using [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-jfrog-cli).

For that purpose I have tried below command at first - which successfully uploaded the package but at wrong path...

```
jfrog rt u *.nupkg folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1/folder1.1.1.1/
```

It considered **folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1/folder1.1.1.1/** as a single folder.

So after going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152582/how-to-upload-an-artifact-to-jfrog-artifactory-using-jfrog-cli) answer, I tried having it's value as `true / false` both but it didn't work and threw an error.

Any suggestion that how can I create a nested folder using [jfrog cli](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue never existed.

The fun part is,

> JFrog doesn't create an empty directory.
>   .

When I tried to create a `Folder1.2` then it displayed nested hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have any official documentation to describe the behavior